# COMMAND=list in /var/log/auth.log... does list refer to the ls command?

Tags: ssh, logs, ls, command

Basically the title. I've been looking through the authentication logs of a compromised virtual machine (it's just a simulation), and I noticed that after the system accepted the hacker's password, the following line ended with the string "COMMAND=list". Does list refer to the ls command?

Answer (score 1):

After some further investigation, by running the `history` command after sudo su-ing the hacker's account, I was able to figure out that COMMAND=list refers to the `sudo -l` command, which lists permitted and prohibited commands for the current user. Just some knowledge for newbies like me.